# What is Unifying Logic within the Semantic Stack Model and who is supposed to take care of it?

Tags: logic, semantic-web

Basically, after hours of researching I still dont get what the Unifying Logic Layer within Semantic Web Stack Model is and whose problem it is to take care of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this depends on what your conceptualisation of the semantic web is. Suppose the ultimate expression of the semantic web is to make heterogeneous information sources available via web-like publishing mechanisms to allow programs - agents - to consume them in order to satisfy some high-level user goal in an autonomous fashion. This is close to [Berners-Lee et al](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=the-semantic-web)'s original conceptualisation of the purpose of the semantic web. In this case, the agents need to know that the information they get from RDF triple stores, SPARQL end-points, rule bases, etc, is reliable, accurate and trustworthy. The semantic web [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web_Stack) postulates that a necessary step to getting to that end-point is to have a logic, or collection of logics, that the agent can use when reasoning about the knowledge it has acquired. It's rather a [strong AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_ai) view, or well towards that end of the spectrum.

However, there's an alternative conceptualisation (and, in fact, there are probably many) in which the top layers of the semantic web stack, including unifying logic, are *not needed*, because that's not what we're asking agents to do. In this view, the semantic web is a way of publishing disaggregated, meaningful information for consumption by programs but not autonomously. It's the developers and/or the users who choose, for example, what information to treat as trustworthy. This is the [linked data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data) perspective, and it follows that the current stack of standards and technologies is perfectly adequate for building useful applications. Indeed, some argue that even well-established standards like [OWL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language) are not necessary for building linked-data applications, though personally I find it essential.

As to whose responsibility it is, if you take the former view it's something the software agent community is already working on, and if you take the latter view it doesn't matter whether something ever gets standardised because we can proceed to build useful functionality without it.